# Python can't open file in same dir

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've met the strange behavior of my python after windows re-installation. python cant find and open text file in the same directory as running script! why?. I'm using python for many years and never had something like that. Now my old scripts which were worked fine before with file open not working at all. I dont want to fix them al. I want to know what is the issue. I have all of the python paths in my environment variables. So the code is just simple and I try to run script from C:\untitled and txt file is also there.

```
import os.path
f = open('mytext.txt')
print(f)
```

So I'm receiving the following output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\untitled\helloworld.py", line 2, in <module>
    f = open('mytext.txt')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'mytext.txt'
```

So what can be the problem? How to fix it? Ive never met the issue like this.

Comment: The problem is that there's no such file. Use absolute path.

Comment: If you `import os` and `print(os.getcwd())`, what does it tell you? How about `print(os.listdir())`?

Comment: are you running program from that directory?

Comment: print(os.getcwd()) - returns me the working dir of script c:\untitled

Comment: At the command prompt where you run python from, does `type mytext.txt` work?

Comment: open a repl and try `import os; os.listdir()` do you see both your py file and your txt tile?

Comment: Sorry guys. Ive found the issue but cant fix it. It works as should if i run the script just from command line. But im using VSCode and when I try to run the script from it the issue occurs. So this is the problem of VSCode settings but I cant find exactly which.

Answer (score 0):

The code you wrote opens the file in read mode by default. But we haven't specified how to print to python, try to print the file as below.

```
import os

f = open('myfile.txt', "r") #open('myfile.txt')
print(f.readline())
```

Cheers

Comment: That is *a* bug, but not *the* bug. Also, it's `readlines`, not `readline`.